# How can I distinguish between one-worded expressions and two-worded expressions?

Tags: c#, c++, natural-language-processing

I was told to create two lists concerning most frequently used words from a plain text (10 Mb arbitrary texts) as monograms (for single worded expressions such as human, water, is) and bigrams  (for two-worded expressions such as basketball team, united states and etc)

I am stuck here and don't know how I can go about it! And how I can distinguish between these two?

My domain is not English, I only gave those examples to make my intention and meaning more clear.

Comment: You may be over-thinking it... a 'bigram' could simply be any pair of adjacent words, not necessarily a related pair.  So in your post, some example bigrams might be "My domain", "domain is", "is not", and "not English".  You should probably get clarification.

Comment: @Hellion there are certain word pairs that have a higher occurrence than random, that *might* be what is desired... though yes, further clarification is a good idea.

Comment: Thank you guys, So if we assume those word pairs that have meanings are desired how should i go about it? 
In first scenario where i can choose any two adjacent words as a pair, i would definitely face problems since i would easily make a meaningful pair into a nonsense ! suppose:
I am a basketbal team player that play in UNITED STATES national team 

I am
a basketbal 
team player
that play 
in UNited 
States national 
team!
See its really hard to understand where to start to how to go about it.:-/

Comment: You might be headed in the direction of the [markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Markov_text_generators) - specifically, the text generator (or at least creating the structure to run one).

Comment: Word pairs without meaning will generally not show up as often as word pairs with meaning.

Comment: @btilly unfortunately that's not the case completely, for instance "this is" or "for instance" and other common english structures may be far more common because they're conversational

Comment: I can't think of how to identify meaningful word pairs without some kind of dictionary of known word pairs.  Word pairs tend to be nouns but not always.  I can't think of a pattern or algorithm to identify them without a dictionary, especially so for other languages.

Comment: In NLP, "bigrams" are always two *adjacent* words in an input stream. So counting frequent bigrams is essentially the same as counting frequent words: keep track of how often each pair of adjacent words occurs, and return the ones with the highest count - the only problem is that storing pair counts requires much more memory.

Comment: @Hossein instead of bigrams wouldn't you be going after collations?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to read from text word by word and make 2 instances of Dictionary, one for monograms and one for bigrams, having the expression as Key and occurrence as Value. With this you can make some statistics about expressions usage.
You can also use database storage for bigger files.